# Retrieving resource's PCI BAR position (Win32, user mode)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-xp, pci

For hardware testing purpose, I would like to enumerate the I/O and memory regions used by PCI/PCIe devices in Win32 (XP and later) and user space (I already know how to do it in kernel mode, but for many reasons I'd prefer to do it in user mode). By using the Configuration Manager API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I can already find all devices' resources. The only thing that I still miss is the position in the PCI registers space of the entries by which each resource has been required. Indeed the resource manager doesn't maintain in general the order of the resources (why should it do it?). Moreover, some devices (e.g. the RTL8168 network controller) have "holes" in BAR register, i.e. the BAR 0 and 2 correspond to some resource while BAR 1 doesn't. Is there a way to obtain the original BAR index of a given resource by some of PNP Configuration Manager API (or other API too)?